# How can I perform a background check on iOS?

Tags: ios, background-process

I am needing to perform a very simple background check for my iOS app. It needs to just make one call to my web server and check the number it retrieves against something in my app. Is it possible to do that kind of background check? If so what can I do to put it together?

EDIT

To clarify what I mean by background: I am meaning background on the phone. When the app is not present. Is it possible to do this request in the background? Obviously with the app not being completely closed out from multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect sort of thing for NSOperationQueue.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

You can write an operation and then put it on the queue when you need it.

Alternatively, and more simply, you can just do a really simple asynchronous call.

```
+ (NSArray *) myGetRequest: (NSURL *) url{

  NSArray *json = [[NSArray alloc] init];

  NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                url];
  NSError *error;

  if (data)
     json = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization
                                           JSONObjectWithData:data
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&error]];

  if (error)
     NSLog(@"%@", error)

  return json;
}
```

and then put it in a simple dispatch block...

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueueA = dispatch_queue_create("updater", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueueA, ^{
    // stuff done here will happen in the background
    NSArray * arrayOfData = [self myGetRequest: myURL];
    // could be array... dictionary... whatever, you control this by returning the type of data model you want from the server formatted as JSON data
    NSString * stringValue = arrayOfData[index];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // perform checking here and do whatever updating you need to do based on the data

    });
});
```

Comment: This definitely looks like a promising way to do it! My ultimate goal is to make this quick check and if the numbers are different send a local notification. When I say 'background' I literally mean the user is not in the app. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Jonathan You can do it entering background, and schedule a Local Notification for later, but you can't check internet after being suspended by the system. Otherwise think at Push Notification and at doing you logic on the server side.

Comment: @Beppe I did look into the local notifications, but the notification should be sent pending the data from the server check. I have looked at some push notification stuff, but it looks pretty difficult considering what it's used for. Is there a simple way to put the server side logic together for something like this? Basically send a push notification if the number retrieved is different from the previous number. If it is set the saved number to the new number. Etc.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm afraid there are no simple ways to implement Push Notifications. But I'm still convinced that what you're looking for is actually Push Notification Services, as they are made for sending notifications to the user even if the app is not running or it is in the background. As I've wrote above, you can't do tasks like internet connection while your app is suspended by the system (~30 seconds after entering background).

Comment: @Beppe If you have a free moment would you be able to answer a few thing's in regards to using the APNS? Just a quick chat would be great!

Comment: Parse has great an easy handling of push notifications, and you get one million a month for free.  It might be worth just implementing that framework initially to test your MVP until you have more time to develop a APNS server.  Also, in django there is a an APNS framework that you can use to more easily set one up.

Comment: @Jonathan I've created a chat room called APNS, go there to ask about APNS, or ask a new question if you think it can help other users too. AdamG, you are welcome too!!

Comment: @beppe I am in the chat room so just stop by whenever you can.

Comment: @Jonathan I just gave you ownership privilege. Let's move this "tip for tap" to the chat room!

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to check your server and retrieve data.

Here my suggestion:

1. Create the file containing your data on the server (e.g. Data.txt)
2. Use NSURLRequest to create a request to Data.txt
3. Use connectionDidFinishLoading to get data from Data.txt
4. Put data from Data.txt in a NSArray
5. Work/compare the array and do your logic

If your server is fast and you have to get just one number, you can do it in the main tread, otherwise use:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
      // your request here  
});
```

to work in a different tread as requested.

And remember to check if internet connection and your server are available with something like Reachability and manage connection error with NSURLRequest delegate

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using Grand Central Dispatch: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial Multithreading and Grand Central Dispatch on iOS.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial